# EntityFramework Core Update-Database throws exception "No DbContext was found in assembly"

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, class-library

I have a project that follows Code-First design and I have n-tier structure so it looks like this:

DataAccessLayer -> BusinesLogicLayer -> ServiceLayer

And I have a seperate Entity Model layer. I want to use Entity Model layer only in DataAccessLayer and pass results in view models to the business logic layer and so on.

I can add migrations without any problems. But when i type `update-database` i get the following error.

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'MyProject.Service'. Ensure that
>   you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither
>   abstract nor generic.

Do I have to reference my `DbContext` directly from the startup project? I feels like I'll have to put all the data access operations in the start up project. Can anyone help?

Comment: In nuget package console make sure that you select the correct project in the "Default project" dropdown list. The one that contain your DbContext.

Comment: ...and the correct project set as the startup project. See [using the tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#using-the-tools).

Comment: CodeNotFound please post your comment as an answer. That's what i was missing. Thank you